# Join two streams using a count-based window

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink Streaming API and I want to complete the following simple (IMO) task. I have two streams and I want to join them using count-based windows. The code I have so far is the following:

```
public class BaselineCategoryEquiJoin {

private static final String recordFile = "some_file.txt";

private static class ParseRecordFunction implements MapFunction<String, Tuple2<String[], MyRecord>> {
    public Tuple2<String[], MyRecord> map(String s) throws Exception {
        MyRecord myRecord = parse(s);
        return new Tuple2<String[], myRecord>(myRecord.attributes, myRecord);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
    ExecutionConfig config = environment.getConfig();
    config.setParallelism(8);
    DataStream<Tuple2<String[], MyRecord>> dataStream = environment.readTextFile(recordFile)
            .map(new ParseRecordFunction());
    DataStream<Tuple2<String[], MyRecord>> dataStream1 = environment.readTextFile(recordFile)
            .map(new ParseRecordFunction());
    DataStreamSink<Tuple2<String[], String[]>> joinedStream = dataStream1
            .join(dataStream)
            .where(new KeySelector<Tuple2<String[],MyRecord>, String[]>() {
                public String[] getKey(Tuple2<String[], MyRecord> recordTuple2) throws Exception {
                    return recordTuple2.f0;
                }
            }).equalTo(new KeySelector<Tuple2<String[], MyRecord>, String[]>() {
                public String[] getKey(Tuple2<String[], MyRecord> recordTuple2) throws Exception {
                    return recordTuple2.f0;
                }
            }).window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
            .apply(new JoinFunction<Tuple2<String[],MyRecord>, Tuple2<String[],MyRecord>, Tuple2<String[], String[]>>() {
                public Tuple2<String[], String[]> join(Tuple2<String[], MyRecord> tuple1, Tuple2<String[], MyRecord> tuple2) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2<String[], String[]>(tuple1.f0, tuple1.f0);
                }
            }).print();
    environment.execute();
}
}
```

My code works without errors, but it does not produce any results. In fact, the call to `apply` method is never called (verified by adding a breakpoint on debug mode). I think, the main reason for the previous is that my data do not have a time attribute. Therefore, windowing (materialized through `window`) is not done properly. Therefore, my question is how can I indicate that I want my join to take place based on count-windows. For instance, I want the join to materialize every 100 tuples from each stream. Is the previous feasible in Flink? If yes, what should I change in my code to achieve it.

At this point, I have to inform you that I tried to call the `countWindow()` method, but for some reason it is not offered by Flink's `JoinedStreams`.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count-based joins are not supported. You could emulate count-based windows, by using "event-time" semantics and apply a unique seq-id as timestamp to each record. Thus, a time-window of "5" would be effectively a count-window of 5.

Comment: Could You please have a look on this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282692/match-based-on-some-property-between-two-data-streams-and-collect-all-based-on-m